# check 'add store code to urls' enabled/not by admin

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, url, store-code

I need to get the exact URL when customer visit my site on first time,
It is based on following options

1. **base url** that depends on default website,store and store view,
2. **store code to urls** enabled or not.

I got the base URL by

```
$websites = Mage::getModel('core/website')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('is_default', 1);
$website = $websites->getFirstItem();
$websiteId = $website->getId();
$websiteCode = $website->getCode();
$baseUrl = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('web/unsecure/base_url', 'website', $websiteCode);
```

The URL will be appended with store code if  **store code to urls** is enabled in admin.

how to check store code to urls enabled programmatically in magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the store codes are included in the URL like this:

```
$flag = Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('web/url/use_store');
```

`$flag` will be `true` or `false` depending on the store codes in URL are enabled or not.